# What is the most efficient way to create instances in loop and save them into another vector

Tags: c++, c++11

```
struct element {
    int start;
    int end;
};
```

I declared class as below

```
class myClass {
public:
    myClass();
    void addElements(element);
    virtual ~myClass();
private:
    int elementCount = 0;
    std::vector<element> includedElems;
};

void motionSet::addVectors(motionVector mv) 
{
    /*A function for adding motion vectors for specific object*/
    includedVectors.push_back(mv);
    vectorCount++;
}
```

Here I am trying to create instances of myClass and if the distance between two consecutive paths, I want to keep them in same class. I wrote the following code:

```
std::vector<myClass> allObjects;
element path;
auto j=series2.begin();
for(auto i = series1.begin(); i < series1.end() ;++i)
{
    path.start = *i;
    path.end = *j;
    if(i!= series1.begin())
    {
        if(checkDistance(*i,*(i-1)))
        {
            //Here I want to add elements to already created instance of myClass, but does not want to resize allObjects. --> PROBLEMATIC PART
            myClass sameObject = *(allObjects.end()-1);
            sameObject.addElements(node);
            allObjects.erase(allObjects.end()-1);
            allObjects.push_back(sameObject);
        }
        else
        {//Here I want to create a new instance of myClass and want to add it to allObjects
            myClass anotherObject;
            anotherObject.addElements(node);
            allObjects.push_back(anotherObject);
            k++;
        }
    }
    else
//Want to create an instance in the first iteration
        {
            myClass firstObject;
            firstObject.addElements(node);
            allObjects.push_back(firstObject);
            k++;
        }
        j++;
    }
```

Although it runs without errors, somehow it does not seem efficient. I tried to use pointer, but it throws exceptions. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: You shouldn't worry about optimization unless you know it is currently or will be an issue.  Over-optimization can easily be a bad thing

Comment: Actually its my obsesiveness. I think there is more efficient way to do this

Comment: @Bhoke - instead of `allObjects.erase(allObjects.end()-1);
            allObjects.push_back(sameObject);`, I suppose you could `allObject.back() = sameObject;` (if there is an `operator=()` in `myClass`)

Comment: this question may also be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Bhoke - sorry but... the part "Here I want to add elements to already created instance of myClass, but does not want to resize allObjects. --> PROBLEMATIC PART" ... why don't you simply `allObjects.back().addElements(node);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure (verify with attention) but seems to me that your code can be rewritten as

```
std::vector<myClass> allObjects;
element path;
auto j=series2.begin();
for(auto i = series1.begin(); i < series1.end() ;++i)
{
    path.start = *i;
    path.end = *j;

    if ( (i == series1.begin()) || ( false == checkDistance(*i, *(i-1)) ) )
    {
        allObjects.emplace_back();
        k++;
    }

    allObjects.back().addElements(node);

    j++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I did not know that I can reach the final element directly by using `back()`

Comment: @Bhoke - you're wellcome. STL containers (especially with C++11 evolutions) are very powerful tools. I suggest you to give a look at the interfaces (see, by example, en.cppreference.com).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the vector::emplace methods to construct an object and add it to a container all at once, thereby avoiding a copy.  See [emplace_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace_back/)